# How to update ListView from other activities

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android, I googled a lot but can't find a proper answer. Someone can help me?
I have two activities, activity 1 contains a listview, activity 2 is an edit view, what I want to do is after clicking the item on the listview, it will go to activity 2, after manipulate data click submit button(submit method), it will go back to listview, and the listview will show the updated result.
Here is my avtivity 1 code

```
public class I4ComponentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String quantity;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_component);

    final ArrayList<ComponentDetail> details = new ArrayList<ComponentDetail>();

    details.add(new ComponentDetail("Screen", "1"));
    details.add(new ComponentDetail("Camera", "2"));
    details.add(new ComponentDetail("Battery", "5"));
    details.add(new ComponentDetail("Change Port", "10"));
    details.add(new ComponentDetail("Speaker", "5"));
    details.add(new ComponentDetail("Power Key", "14"));
    details.add(new ComponentDetail("Screen Cable", "24"));

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.component_list);
    DetailAdapter detailAdapter = new DetailAdapter(I4ComponentActivity.this, details);
    listView.setAdapter(detailAdapter);


    // Set a click listener to edit quantity when the list item is clicked on
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            ComponentDetail cd = details.get(position);
            quantity = cd.getQuantity();
            Intent i = new Intent(I4ComponentActivity.this, Edit.class);
            //Create the bundle
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            //Add your data to bundle
            bundle.putString("Item_quantity", quantity);
            //Add the bundle to the intent
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            //Fire that second activity
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Here is activity 2 code

```
public class Edit extends AppCompatActivity {
private int quantity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);


    //Get the bundle
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    //Extract the data…
    String Item_quantity = bundle.getString("Item_quantity");

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_edit);
    tv.setText(Item_quantity);
    quantity  = Integer.parseInt(Item_quantity);
}

public void decrease(View v){

    quantity --;
    displayQuantity();
}
public void increase(View v){

    quantity ++;
    displayQuantity();
}
public void submit(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(Edit.this, I4ComponentActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("quantity_back", ""+quantity);
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void displayQuantity(){
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_edit);
    tv.setText(""+quantity);
}
}
```

Comment: look at `startActivityForResult`

Comment: Thank you, you answered so fast, startActivityForResult is what I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

StartActivity2 with `startActivityForResult(Intent,1)`

After you get what you want in Aty2 `setResult(1,Intent)`

And rewrite `onActivityResult` you will get the back intent.

After add item to your arraylist. Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`to refresh you listview

If you don't clear. There must have a lot of information in Google

Comment: Thank you, startActivityForResult is exactly what I need to use, I need to improve my searching skill :)